# using CompositeScript to combine scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using `CompositeScript` to combine JS into one file for sending.
But I have the `AjaxScriptManager` in the masterpage and not in every aspx page. So should I include all my javascript file references inside the `CompositeScript` in the masterpage, or should I place an `AjaxScriptManager` in every aspx page and add to the `CompositeScript`  only the JS files that are specific for that page?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the ScriptManager on the master page and include script files needed by many pages.  On a per page level you can additionally add a ScriptManagerProxy where you can add sets off one off scripts to be combined as needed.

ScriptManagerProxy
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx